# GCE gcutil command results in INVALID_FIELD_VALUE

Tags: runtime-error, google-compute-engine, gcutil

I'm trying to create a Google Cloud instance. I'm running this:

```
gcutil addinstance test03 --persistent_boot_disk --machine_type=n1-standard-1 --zone=us-central2-a --image=projects/debian-cloud/global/images/debian-7-wheezy-v20130617
```

It's failing with an error of **INVALID_FIELD_VALUE** and a message of:

> Invalid value for field 'resource fault. Resource was not found.

I've tried several variations, and all are giving the same thing. I thought I had previously had this working. Why isn't this working?

Comment: Can you try `--image=debian-7-wheezy-v20130617` ?

Comment: That command worked fine for me. Might want to check your version of gcutil (via 'gcutil version') and make sure you're on the latest release (1.8.2 as of this writing).

Comment: Command got [deprecated a while ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31304351/google-cloud-compute-gcutil-deprecated)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Cloud Compute "gcutil" deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31304351/google-cloud-compute-gcutil-deprecated)