# Google Cloud Compute "gcutil" deprecated

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

I'm new to Google Cloud Compute and I'm no developer or coder. But I've been following the information step by step guide. http://www.filiwiese.com/running-screaming-frog-on-google-cloud/

Unfortunately as of today "gcutil" has deprecated and I'm at a loss how to follow the instructions.

I tried understanding Googles info but no joy.

I'm hoping that someone can explain to me how to proceed.

Thanks

Comment: see the official google documentation. its well explained there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `gcutil` tool has been deprecated in favor of `gcloud`, part of Google Cloud SDK.

There's a [guide to translating `gcutil` commands to `gcloud` commands](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gcloud-compute/transition-gcloud-gcutil), e.g.:

> Create an instance:
>
> - `gcutil addinstance INSTANCE`
> - `gcloud compute instances create INSTANCE`
>
> Delete an instance:
>
> - `gcutil deleteinstance INSTANCE`
> - `gcloud compute instances delete INSTANCE \
>       [--keep-disks {boot,all,none}]`

Other commands are listed in the document.

Comment: Thank you Misha, that links explains it well. I'm not sure why I didn't come across that article but thanks again :)